# How do you access tables not in the default Oracle schema using dplyr?

Tags: r, oracle, dplyr, nanodbc

With the release of `dplyr 0.7.0`, it is now supposedly easy to connect to Oracle using the `odbc` package. However, I am running into a problem accessing tables not inside the default schema (for me it is my username). For example, suppose there is the table `TEST_TABLE` in schema `TEST_SCHEMA`. Then, example SQL syntax to get data would be: `select * from TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE'`.

To do the same in `dplyr, I am trying the following:

```
# make database connection using odbc: [here's a guide][1]
oracle_con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "DB")
# attempt to get table data
tbl(oracle_con, 'TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE')
```

Now, this leads to an error message:

```
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT *
FROM ("TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE") "zzz12"
WHERE (0 = 1)'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I think the problem here is the double quotation marks, as:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(oracle_con, "select * from (TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE) where rownum < 100;")
```

works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for a while until I found the solution at the bottom of the [introduction](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/06/27/dbplyr-1-1-0/) to `dbplyr`. The correct syntax to specify the schema and table combo is:

```
tbl(oracle_con, in_schema('TEST_SCHEMA', 'TEST_TABLE'))
```

As an aside, I think the issue with quotation marks is lodged here: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3080

There are also the following alternate work-arounds that may be suitable depending on what you wish to do. Since the connection used `DBI`, one can alter the schema via:

```
DBI::dbSendQuery(oracle_con, "alter session set current_schema = TEST_SCHEMA")
```

after which `tbl(oracle_con, 'TEST_TABLE')` will work.

Or, if you have create view privileges, you can create a "shortcut" in your default schema to any table you are interested in:

```
DBI::dbSendQuery(oracle_con, "CREATE VIEW TEST_TABLE AS SELECT *
                 FROM TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_TABLE")
```

Note that the latter *may* be more suitable for applications where you wish to copy local data to the database for a join, but do not have write access to the table's original schema.